# Is this error caused by using React code-splitting with component inheritance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen quite a few questions that asks about `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` error. Usually it's caused by not extending from `React.Component` or some typo. However in my case I'm sure that everything is correct. It's quite a big code base (120k+ LOC). This error started showing up after introducing code splitting. Only thing I've done is that I've wrapped few `Switch` components into `React.Suspense` and changed route components imports to `React.lazy`.

Facebook development team recommends to use Composition over Inheritance but they don't specify any use cases where this might be a problem. Couple of our components uses inheritance. They just inherit from some component that has additional functions. Could this be the issue? That we use inheritance?

This is the code of the second latest call from stack trace

```
class App extends BaseApp {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hello, edited

Comment: Is BassApp a functional component?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis It's not. However it is also loaded lazily

Comment: could you add BaseApp's declaration, constructor, and return? (everything but its methods)

Comment: There's no constructor or return. There's just componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and one function. Seems like it's supposed to call some redux action on different pathname

Comment: and the declaration is "class BaseApp extends React.Component {" No errand characters like "()" and if you're using Component, its imported as {Component} ?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis Exactly. Everything should be correct. That's why I'm thinking that it's caused by lazy loading

Comment: I tested a very simple lazyload inheritence, and that caused no errors.

Comment: I have something like this with `inheritance` and `React.lazy`, but everything works fine